# Как правильно читать

Tags: синтаксис

*В границах водоохранных зон запрещаются:

движение и стоянка транспортных средств (кроме специальных транспортных средств), за исключением их движения по дорогам и стоянки на дорогах и в специально оборудованных местах, имеющих твердое покрытие.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, выражение «имеющих твердое покрытие» относится ко всему предложению или к выражению «в специально оборудованных местах»?

Answer (score 1):

Ко всему предложению это выражение относиться не может, но неоднозначность есть. По смыслу можно догадаться, что авторы имели в виду *только* "*специально оборудованные места*", однако грамматически твёрдое покрытие можно в равной мере отнести и к "*дорогам*", упомянутым в том же падеже перед союзом "и". Противоречия при таком понимании не возникает, поскольку дороги бывают и без покрытия.